# Angular (angular 2+) Vs Ext Js 6 performance

Tags: javascript, angular, extjs6, dom-manipulation

If you have to select between ext Js 6 and Angular2+ , how you will check the performance or on what basis you will say that the one is better then then other. 
When it comes to performance with modern browsers which one is better to use.

Comment: The comparison you ask for does not make sense. It depends so much on the application and the way it is written, there cannot be any general performance comparison like you ask for. Both answers give good points.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the project and the team.

Extjs standard edition is sold for around $4500, the sencha test will cost you another $1000 (I guess).

If you are an individual developer then you have to meet certain requirements to get the licence.

So my point is ---

If you are a big corporate and have various application, only then Extjs makes sense as you will get dedicated support.

Since Extjs is theme based, developers don't have to worry about the design and concentrate on functionality.

On the other hand if you are an individual developer, Angular JS makes more sense.

So, I think this comparison between Angular and Extjs is not correct. Both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: There is also a GPL version of ExtJs.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer yes you are correct. My answer was more from a commercial point of view.

Comment: I agree with all you said, it was just a little complement. I've chosen ExtJs in the past when the GPL version was better maintained. Today I wouldn't choose it anymore, because the GPL version receives less and less attention.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ext JS 6 and Angular 2+ both are JavaScript Framework but have a different concept.
2. Ext JS 6 is not open source while Angular is open source framework.
3. If need to create Single page application, Angular is a good framework.
4. Angular 2 is based on typescript while Ext JS 6 is Javascript framework.  That's a reason Angular works faster.
5. Angular performance is faster because of Dependency Injection (DI) feature.
6. Ext JS 6 have there owned UI Component while Angular works with Bootstrap or Angular Material, so If need to create fancy look application, Angular is a first choice.
7. If you have to develop a big ERP system, Ext JS 6 is a better option.
8. Angular support Component-based architecture that's why it is easy to develop an app in this and works faster.
9. Ext JS 6 is completely JS written framework while in Angular we should know both HTML and JS.

Comment: so when it comes to performance dom rendering and manipulation any benchmark or test which can be give which is faste. can it be produced ?

Comment: ExtJs is open-source, at least the core part. There's a GPL version of it.